# How to provide int[,] and int values to test method, C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I need this method for unit testing. There is matrix and method that calculate matrix trace which is integer. So i need to provide simple matrix (int[,]) and expected trace:

```
[DynamicData(nameof(TestDataMethod), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void TestReturnTrace(int[,] simpleMatrix, int expected)
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMatrixGenerator>();

    mock.Setup(a => a.GenerateRandomMatrix()).Returns(simpleMatrix);

    MatrixBase matrix = new MatrixBase(mock.Object);

    int actual = matrix.ReturnTrace();

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

How can i create simple 2D array and integer value and return it?

My best attempt is:

```
    static IEnumerable<object[], int> TestDataMethod()
    {
        int[,] array2d = new int[,] { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };
        int myInteger = 2;

        return (new[] { 
            new[] { array2d }, 
            myInteger )
        };
    }
```

but the error is "No best type found for implicitly-typed array", like if I try to create array, but I just pair two values in parentheses. Where am I wrong?

Comment: See [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` accepts only one type parameter

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I guess that was just to show what OP wants: a list of tuples basically.

Comment: Well he actually asked how to return IEnumerable<object[], int> and the answer is : you can't cause it's illegal.

Comment: @Andrey, could you please share your test method? Your return type has `object[]`, but you declare it `int[,]`

Comment: Are you sure about DynamicData expecting an IEnumerable<object[], int>? IMHO it expects an IEnumerable<object[]>, where object[] contains all parameters of a single test case, while the enumeration loops over the test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return type doesn't match the method data, you can use [`tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) `(int[,], int)` as generic type parameter for `IEnumerable<T>` and `yield return` to return a single item.

```cs
static IEnumerable<(int[,], int)> TestDataMethod()
{
    int[,] array2d = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };
    int myInteger = 2;

    yield return (array2d, myInteger);
}
```

**Update**: just looked at some articles regarding MSTest and `DynamicData` attribute, like [this](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm). The correct approach seems to be using an `IEnumerable<object[]>`, where every item in object array represents a single argument in test method

```cs
static IEnumerable<object[]> TestDataMethod()
{
    int[,] array2d = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };
    int myInteger = 2;

    yield return new object[] { array2d, myInteger };
}
```